# I am not able to use a friend function properly

Tags: c++

I am writing a code to declare a member function of a class as a friend, but I am getting errors.
The code is

```
#include<iostream>

class Vect;

class Coordinate {
    float x;
    float y;

public:
    Coordinate(float a,float b):x(a),y(b){}// constructor
    Coordinate():x(0),y(0){};//constructor
    display()
    {
        std::cout<<"\nx:"<<x<<" "<<"y:"<<y;
    }
    friend Vect::add(Coordinate B);
};

class Vect {
public:
    add(Coordinate A)
    {
        std::cout<<A.x;
    }
};
```

The exact errors are

> invalid use of incomplete type 'class Vect'| and forward declaration
>   of 'class Vect'|

Comment: Please have a bash at formatting the code to make it readable

Comment: You cannot declare a function without a return type in ISO C++.

Comment: `add(Coordinate A)` is not a valid function declaration, you are missing a return type

Comment: And get it to compile i.e. first error is `prog.cpp:10:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘display’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 display()`

Comment: The compiler complains about class `Vec` being incomplete... so make it complete.

Comment: @user9212993 [You can](https://tio.run/##dc3BCgIhFIXhvU8htBkX9QAqgfUO7e1eJy44KqNGMMyz2wwTFEXbw893IKX9DaC1HQXwFZ2mmMvo7HBk4G3O/BzjiBRsceq1XByUiaV69QSScX6PhNwidu@UG6HYrH6Iacl7H23hD/Uh9CO5gBu06lJ@caeN@x8YsdK5oJQQa9HaHJaHmQ2WQiemubUn).

Comment: @user202729 Must have been an old constraint in c++03. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I am using c11 so other functions without a return type(even void) are compiling without problems.

Comment: @user9212993 [You can in C++03](https://tio.run/##dc3dCsIgFMDxe59C6GZjFEF3asHqHboddnRDcCpTIxh79cyxoC@6ODfn/PkdcG7dAaS0UgZ0FJIp68MgeX9AoLn3@GTtIJThQdLn5iwhjMjFi1ZAEMZXqwTmQhSvFNclRRP9Icact9rygG/0TWgHJY1YoFkn5Is7Ltz/oC5n2gdBCNgYGKs3@cOEeq5M8XnDjOGmAaejnydXKd2h1bzzaZ2rPVTVdvcA).

Comment: @user8865657 C != C++.

Comment: This code would compile even less in C11 than in C++11 - it's invalid in both language standards

Comment: Most likely some compiler extension. Learn standard C++ please. And yes, C doesn't have `<iostream>` header.

Comment: sorry i meant c++11

Comment: Why are you using `friend` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

```
  class Y; //forward declaration of class Y
  class X
  {
  public:
        int getmark(Y);
  };

  class Y
  {
  int mark;
   public:
   Y() {}
   friend int X::getmark(Y);
   };

   int X::getmark(Y obj) {
   cin >> obj.mark;
  return obj.mark;
  }

int main()
{
  X a;
  Y b;
  a.getmark(b);
}
```

At first, when the object a (class X) is created, a forward declaration of class Y is necessary in order to declare the Y argument to X::getmark().

Creating object b (class Y) wont be a problem as the compiler knows class X exists (for the friend function).

Then, simply call the function getmark() through the object a.

Note: It is necessary to declare the function getmark() after the declaration of class Y, or else compiler will consider the class Y as an incomplete type.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is bad - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Still where is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
class Vect;
class Coordinate
{
 public:
  Coordinate(float a = 0f, float b = 0f) :x(a), y(b) {}// constructor
  float x;
  float y;
void display()
{
    std::cout << "\nx:" << x << " " << "y:" << y;
}
  friend int add(Coordinate B);
};
class Vect
{
  friend int add(Coordinate B);
public:

};

int add(Coordinate B)
{
   std::cout << B.x << std::endl;
   return B.x;
}
```

Comment: `Coordinate(float a = 0f, float b = 0f) :x(a), y(b) {}` -> Then get rid of the other constructor

Comment: So does that mean that a single member function of another class cannot be a friend to another class?

Comment: you're missing a `return` in `add` (or you need to change it to a `void` return type)

Comment: @user8865657 see follow example

Comment: Without the `return` calling it invokes *undefined behavior* - that's quite an issue, wouldn't you agree?